# Create Google Extension that can process with Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Halo, I need to develop a Google extension that able to link with python. I already write the process code in the python, all I need is a extension that can scrape the Twitter ID and Tweet, and process through the python and send back the result from python to extension. Is it posible? What library need to use? It will something like pass messages between the extension and python program.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a python interpreter implemented in javascript, like [Brython](https://brython.info/index.html) for example.

Another option is to create a python web server that listens for requests with twitter ids and responds with the processed information. Your extension will then communicate with the python server same as any other api server.